# Fallback fonts with different types (sans serif, cursive etc)?

Tags: css

Can I write my `font-family` rule to include multiple fonts where not all fonts are sans-serif or serif or cursive?

I want to use a `cursive` font, but need a fallback that is `sans-serif'.

How can I go about this?

The two fonts, written in separate `font-family` rules would apear like this:

`font-family: 'Overlock', cursive;`

and

`font-family: Arial, sans-serif;`

Is there a way to use both, where Arial is the fallback?

Comment: Are you talking about fallback for the entire document? Or specific to DOM elements and their children? Realistically on your document you'd set the global expectation for font(s) eg `html { font-family: font1, font2, font3 }` and then say if you want cursive on one section you'd set a separate class on a parent element eg `.cursive { font-family: cursive, Arial }` with like `<div class="cursive">cursive text with arial fallback</div>` or perhaps I'm not understanding the question?

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I think you understood my question correctly. My particular case is that I want to use a particular font in an HTML email (Overlock, which is cursive) but, knowing that many email clients won't support it especially as I'm loading in via an @import statement, I want to provide a fallback (and I want to explicitly declare the fallback, rather than leaving it up to the email client to choose a font). I've chosen to use Arial as the fallback.